# Does spring cloud contract supports callback response imitation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, stubbing, spring-cloud-contract

I dont mean supporting async responses (like described here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#contract-dsl-async).
I mean situation when after my request I get response synchronously. And after that I want to get some request back from stub. Smth like this:

1. request from my service to stub:

POST /subscription {subscription params...}

2. synchronous response from stub:

202 Accepted

3. after a while request from stub to my service:

POST /subscription-answer {subscription with more params...}